# Create additional variables/placeholders for Woocommerce email notifications subject

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, placeholder, email-notifications

When activating new email notifications from Custom order statuses I have this options for Subject placeholders:

> "You can use the following placeholders: {order_date}, {order_number}, {order_status}, {billing_first_name}, {billing_last_name}, {billing_company}, {blogname}, {site_title}"

Is there a way of creating new placeholders for other fields? 
Basically, I have created a new hidden field called test_pw and I want to be able to add {billing_email} and {test_pw} to my custom emails.

I have tried with this code kindly suggested but I am not sure how to format it.

```
// Only for woocommerce versions 3.2 + (up to 3.2)
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_format_string' , 'filter_email_format_string', 20, 2 );
function filter_email_format_string( $string, $email ) {
// Get the instance of the WC_Order object
$order = $email->object;

// Additional wanted placeholders in the array of find / relace pairs
$additional_placeholders = array(
    '{custom_one}'      => __('my replacement one','woocommerce'),
    '{billing_email}'   => $order->get_billing_email(),
    '{test_pw}'   => $order->get_test_pw(),
);

// return the clean string with new replacements
return str_replace( array_keys( $additional_placeholders ), array_values( $additional_placeholders ), $string );
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is an example that will show you how to add new placeholders for email notifications Subject:

```
// Only for woocommerce versions 3.2 + (up to 3.2)
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_format_string' , 'filter_email_format_string', 20, 2 );
function filter_email_format_string( $string, $email ) {
    // Get the instance of the WC_Order object
    $order = $email->object;

    // Additional wanted placeholders in the array of find / relace pairs
    $additional_placeholders = array(
        '{custom_one}'      => __('my replacement one','woocommerce'),
        '{shipping_city}'   => $order->get_shipping_city(),
        '{yudu_pw}'         => $order->get_meta( 'yudu_pw' ), // <=== HERE
    );

    // return the clean string with new replacements
    return str_replace( array_keys( $additional_placeholders ), array_values( $additional_placeholders ), $string );
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme).* Tested and works **only for Woocommerce version 3.2 and up…**

Comment: I am trying but can't quite figure it out. I want to include the customer's email addres and the hidden field I created I called test_pw.
'{billing_email}'   => $order->get_billing_email(),
'{test_pw}'      => $order->get_test_pw(),

Comment: thanks a lot but I am not good enough to know where and how to insert the code inside the rest. Thanks for trying, but you are probably assuming I am a programer lol

Comment: I amended the question

Comment: It doesn't work for footer text. To add custom placeholders to footer text extend woocommerce_email_footer_text filter.