# Additional placeholders for Woocommerce email notifications subject with ACF

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields, email-notifications

I'm searching a way of creating new placeholders for subject and recipients email when a new order is create? I have created new fields with ACF : "chantier" and "conducteur de travaux" called and I want to be able to add {chantier} in my subject mail and add {conducteur} to my recipient.

Here my code for ACF field :

```
 if( function_exists('acf_add_local_field_group') ):

 acf_add_local_field_group(array(
'key' => 'group_5c49b50b45a52',
'title' => 'Nom du chantier',
'fields' => array(
    array(
        'key' => 'field_5c49b5127665d',
        'label' => 'Chantier',
        'name' => 'chantier',
        'type' => 'post_object',
        'instructions' => '',
        'required' => 0,
        'conditional_logic' => 0,
        'wrapper' => array(
            'width' => '',
            'class' => '',
            'id' => '',
        ),
        'show_fields_options' => array(
            0 => 'order',
            1 => 'email',
        ),
        'post_type' => array(
            0 => 'chantier',
        ),
        'taxonomy' => '',
        'allow_null' => 0,
        'multiple' => 0,
        'return_format' => 'object',
        'ui' => 1,
    ),
    array(
        'key' => 'field_5c541edb71030',
        'label' => 'Conducteur de travaux',
        'name' => 'conducteur_de_travaux',
        'type' => 'user',
        'instructions' => '',
        'required' => 0,
        'conditional_logic' => 0,
        'wrapper' => array(
            'width' => '',
            'class' => '',
            'id' => '',
        ),
        'show_fields_options' => array(
            0 => 'order',
            1 => 'email',
        ),
        'role' => array(
            0 => 'conducteur-de-travaux',
        ),
        'allow_null' => 0,
        'multiple' => 0,
        'return_format' => 'array',
    ),
),
'location' => array(
    array(
        array(
            'param' => 'checkout',
            'operator' => '==',
            'value' => 'wc-before-billing-form',
        ),
    ),
),
'menu_order' => 0,
'position' => 'normal',
'style' => 'default',
'label_placement' => 'top',
'instruction_placement' => 'label',
'hide_on_screen' => '',
'active' => 1,
'description' => '',
 ));

 endif;
```

I have tried with this code suggested here :

[Create additional variables/placeholders for Woocommerce email notifications subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50120643/create-additional-variables-placeholders-for-woocommerce-email-notifications-sub)

But it doesn't works, here my code :

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_format_string' ,           'add_custom_email_format_string', 20, 2 );
function add_custom_email_format_string( $string, $email ) {
    // The post meta key used to save the value in the order post meta data
    $meta_key = '_chantier';

    // Get the instance of the WC_Order object
    $order    = $email->object;

    // Get the value
    $value  = get_field( $meta_key, $order_id );

    // Additional subject placeholder
    $new_placeholders = array( '{chantier}' => $value );

    // Return the clean replacement value string for "{chantier}" placeholder
    return str_replace( array_keys( $additional_placeholders ), array_values( $additional_placeholders ), $string );
}
```

When I receive the mail I have it : Order {chantier}.
I don't know where is my mistake...

And for the field "conducteur-de-travaux" (user field), I would like to recover the email of the "conducteur de travaux" and add it to the new order recipient email. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

> **Note:** On stackOverFlow to avoid your question to be closed for "too broad" reason, always ask one small question **instead of asking multiple distinct questions at once.** The rule is one answer to one question.

There is some errors and mistakes in your code like `$order_id` that is not defined, so it can't work.

You need to be sure of the meta_key to be used to get the ACF value. It seem that it should be **`'chantier'`** instead of `'_chantier'` *(You can try **both** of them to see which one works)*.

The code below will ad new placeholders for email notifications subject for ACF value:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_format_string', 'add_custom_email_format_string', 10, 2 );
function add_custom_email_format_string( $string, $email ) {

    // HERE the ACF slug to be used to get the value
    $meta_key = 'chantier';
    
    // Get the instance of the WC_Order object
    $order   = $email->object;
    
    // Get ACF value (with the correct Order ID)
    $value = get_field( $meta_key, $order->get_id() );
    
    // Additional subject placeholder
    $new_placeholders = array( '{chantier}' => $value );
    
    // Get the clean replacement value string for "{chantier}" placeholder
    return str_replace( array_keys( $additional_placeholders ), array_values( $additional_placeholders ), $string );
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). It should works now.

Related working answers:

- [Create additional variables/placeholders for Woocommerce email notifications subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50120643/create-additional-variables-placeholders-for-woocommerce-email-notifications-sub/50122476#50122476)
- [Add a custom placeholder to email subject in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55570847/add-a-custom-placeholder-to-email-subject-in-woocommerce/55571932#55571932)
- [Add the product name to the email subject in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55686844/add-the-product-name-to-the-email-subject-in-woocommerce/55695674#55695674)