# Add a custom placeholder to email subject in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, email-notifications

I have a Woocommerce shop and I wanted to add a `delivery_date` after I accept the payment.

I create a custom field in the order section named `delivery_date` with a date value.

Now I wanted to use this custom field as a placeholder in email notification subject, like:

> Your order is now {order_status}. Order details are shown below for your reference: deliverydate: {delivery_date}

I think the placeholder don't work like this, I need to change something in the php but I don't know where.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To add a custom active placeholder `{delivery_date}` in woocommerce email subject, you will use the following hooked function.

You will check before, that `delivery_date` is the correct post meta key used to save the checkout field value to the order *(check in `wp_postmeta` database table for the order `post_id`)*.

The code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_format_string' , 'add_custom_email_format_string', 10, 2 );
function add_custom_email_format_string( $string, $email ) {
    $meta_key    = 'delivery_date'; // The post meta key used to save the value in the order
    $placeholder = '{delivery_date}'; // The corresponding placeholder to be used
    $order = $email->object; // Get the instance of the WC_Order Object
    $value = $order->get_meta($meta_key) ? $order->get_meta($meta_key) : ''; // Get the value

    // Return the clean replacement value string for "{delivery_date}" placeholder
    return str_replace( $placeholder, $value, $string );
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). It should works.

Then in Woocommerce > Settings > Emails > "New Order" notification, you will be able to use the dynamic placeholder `{delivery_date}`…

Comment: get a error
Warning: array_values() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given 

its on the return line

i putted the code into a php snippe, i think it should work there too or?

Comment: @Kim I have no errors… I have made a light update… You need to be sure that the correct meta_key used on wp_postmeta database table is `delivery_date`… If not uou need to change it in the function code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print value of "delivery_date" in email content then you can do like this.

```
$content = "Your order is now %%order_status%%. Order details are shown below for your reference: deliverydate: %%delivery_date%%";
$search_array = ["{order_status}","{delivery_date}"]
$replace_array = [$valueOfOrderStatus,$valueOfDeliveryDate];
$content = str_replace($search_array, $replace_array, $content);
```

Comment: Using this code you can all replace all variables in the content by just adding all search and replace items to the search and replace arrays.

Answer (score 0):

In your Email class (that extends `WC_Email`) you can just call for the `format_string` method.

It will replace the current placeholders with the correct values.
You just need to make sure you have defined them before calling it.

For example:

```php
public function get_default_subject() {
    $this->placeholders['{foo}'] = 'bar';
    return $this->format_string(__( 'Hello {foo}.', 'my-plugin'));
}
```