# Adding placeholder with ACF value for woocommerce email order received

Tags: woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to add a dynamic placeholder `{tipo_ordine}` to the subject on WooCommerce email notifications.

I tried *[Additional placeholders for Woocommerce email notifications subject with ACF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54477762/additional-placeholders-for-woocommerce-email-notifications-subject-with-acf/54478169#54478169)* answer code, making some minor changes to it:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_format_string', 'add_custom_email_format_string', 10, 2 );
function add_custom_email_format_string( $string, $email ) {

    // HERE the ACF slug to be used to get the value
    $meta_key = 'tipo_ordine';

    // Get the instance of the WC_Order object
    $order   = $email->object;

    // Get ACF value (with the correct Order ID)
    $value = get_field( $meta_key, $order->get_id() );

    // Additional subject placeholder
    $new_placeholders = array( '{tipo_ordine}' => $value );

    // Get the clean replacement value string for "{tipo_ordine}" placeholder
    return str_replace( array_keys( $additional_placeholders ), array_values( $additional_placeholders ), $string );
}
```

But It doesn't work. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Can you put some var_dump calls in the function to check what actual values you have got? For example, what is $order_id, where is that set?

Comment: It's an error it would be $order->id I will modify!

Comment: sorry, $order->get_id()

Comment: Does it work now or should I have another look?

Comment: No it doesn't work, so I change subject of new order email via another function, no placeholder!

Comment: if I change $new_placeholders to $additional_placeholders, it replaces the placeholder, but $value returns always null, so it replaces with white space.

Comment: If $value is always returning null that means that that ACF field ('tip_ordine') has not been setup or populated. Are you sure that that field has been defined?